# Print non-existent files from a pipe input

Tags: linux, files, sed, grep, ls

I have a directory of lots of `.PDF` and `.JPG` files.

There should be a `.JPG` file for each `.PDF` with the same name.
I'm trying to use a command to find `.PDF` files that doesn't have a `.JPG` file.

My current command is:

```
find -iname '*.jpg' -print0|sed 's/jpg$/pdf$/ig' |xargs -0 ls
```

This prints `: No such file or directory` error for non-existing files;
the problem is the errors of `ls` cannot be handled by `grep` or `sed` .
Any of these solves my problem:

- How can I make `ls` only list files that doesn't exists?
- How to handle/filter errors of `ls` with `sed`/`grep`?
- any other way for file existence check (without creating bash script files)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be using a loop

```
IFR=$'\0' # because you use -print0 on your find
for jpg_file in `find -iname '*.jpg' -print0`
do
  pdf_file=`echo "$jpg_file" | sed 's/jpg$/pdf/i'`
  if [ -e "$pdf_file" ]; then
    echo "$pdf_file exist"
  else
    echo "$pdf_file missing"
  fi
done
```

Comment: What shell is that? zsh is the only shell I know that supports having NUL characters in its variables, but it doesn't have a IFR variable. If you have multiline file names, the the `sed` command would change jpg to pdf at the end of **every** line, so you should make it: `sed '$s/jpg$/pdf/i'`

Answer (score 2):

With zsh,

```
setopt extendedglob
print -rl -- **/*.(#i)jpg(e{'[[ ! -e $REPLY:r.pdf ]]'})
```

Would report the `jpg` files that don't have a corresponding `pdf` file.

If you want to consider `PDF` and `PdF` files:

```
print -rl -- **/*.(#i)jpg(e{'f=($REPLY:r.(#i)pdf(N)); ((!$#f))'})
```

Of course, instead of printing them, you loop over them like:

```
for f (**/...) convert $f $f:r.pdf
```

`:r` gives the *root name* (that is without the extension) of a file name (`csh` heritage), `(#i)` turns on case insensitive globbing (when `extendedglob` is on), The `e{some code}` globbing qualifier is to run `some code` to determine whether a file should be globbed or not.

Note that it would skip hidden files (those whose name starts with a dot). Add the `D` globbing qualifier to add them back.

Answer (score 2):

POSIXly, you could do:

```
find . -name '*.[jJ][pP][gG]' -exec sh -c '
  for i do
    [ -e "${i%.*}.pdf" ] || printf "%s\n" "$i"
  done' sh {} +
```

If you want to search for PDF files case-insensitively, you would do:

```
find . -name '*.[jJ][pP][gG]' -exec sh -c '
  for i do
    set -- "${i%.*}".[pP][dD][fF]
    case $1 in
      (*"]") printf "%s\n" "$i"
    esac
  done' sh {} +
```

Comment: Just for the word "POSIXly" this deserves an upvote :D

Comment: @user7000, [a few more for you to upvote](/search?q=%22POSIXly%22) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This should help you:

```
find . -iname '*.pdf' -exec bash -c '[[ -f $(echo $(echo {}|sed "s/pdf/jpg/")) ]] || echo $(echo {}|sed "s/pdf/jpg/") not found' \;
```

PDF files that do not have corresponding JPG files will be echoed.

Comment: What do you think would happen if someone managed to put a file called `x;rm -rf ~;.jpg` in the current directory? Beside being non-portable, embedding `{}` like that in arguments to the commands passed to `find`'s `-exec` should be banned of one's habits if only for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Here I have the following sample directory.

```
a1.jpg
a1.pdf
a2.jpg
a2.pdf
a3.pdf
a4.pdf
```

This command will print out a 2 for each `PDF` file that has a corresponding `JPG` file and a 1 for `PDFs` that don't.

```
% find . -type f|sed 's/pdf\|jpg//'|sort|uniq -c|sed 's/$/pdf/'
  2 ./a1.pdf
  2 ./a2.pdf
  1 ./a3.pdf
  1 ./a4.pdf
```

Using the `1` and `2` in the output you can `grep` for either and pipe this on to `xargs` or whatever you want to.

For example:

List of files that have `JPG`.

```
% find . -type f|sed 's/pdf\|jpg//'|sort|uniq -c|sed 's/$/pdf/' |grep " 1 "|awk 
'{print $2}'
./a3.pdf
./a4.pdf
```

List of files that don't have `JPG`.

```
% find . -type f|sed 's/pdf\|jpg//'|sort|uniq -c|sed 's/$/pdf/' |grep " 2 "|awk '{print $2}'
./a1.pdf
./a2.pdf
```

Passing them along to `xargs ls`.

```
% find . -type f|sed 's/pdf\|jpg//'|sort|uniq -c|sed 's/$/pdf/' |grep " 2 "|awk '{print $2}'|xargs ls
./a1.pdf  ./a2.pdf
```

Passing them along to `xargs ls -l`.

```
% find . -type f|sed 's/pdf\|jpg//'|sort|uniq -c|sed 's/$/pdf/' |grep " 2 "|awk '{print $2}'|xargs ls -l
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Dec 27 00:14 ./a1.pdf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Dec 27 00:14 ./a2.pdf
```